# How can I separate SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume that I have the following queries

```
select userName, password, email 
from tblUsersProfile 
where email = '145' or userName = '112'

select userName, password, email 
from tblUsersProfile 
where email = '80' or userName = '70'

select userName, password, email 
from tblUsersProfile 
where email = '129' or userName = '169'

select userName, password, email 
from tblUsersProfile 
where email = '1' or userName = '2'

select 
    AVG(PokemonLevel) as AvgLevel, PokemonId 
from 
    tblUsersPokemons 
group by 
    PokemonId 
order by 
    PokemonId asc

insert into tblOnlineUsersCounts  
   select 
      (select 
          COUNT(LastMoveTime) 
       from 
          tblUsersProfile 
       where 
          LastMoveTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, sysutcdatetime())),  
      (select 
          COUNT(LastMoveTime) 
       from 
          tblUsersProfile 
       where 
          LastMoveTime > DATEADD(DAY, -7, sysutcdatetime())),
      (select 
          COUNT(LastMoveTime) 
       from 
          tblUsersProfile 
       where 
          LastMoveTime > DATEADD(DAY, -30, sysutcdatetime()))

select 
    count(Id) as TotalCount, PokemonId 
from 
    tblUsersPokemons 
group by 
    PokemonId 
order by 
    PokemonId asc
```

Now when I execute them in SQL Server Management Studio, it tries all and if one fails all fails which means all of them is counted as a single query

Also when I right click in SSMS and click **analyze query in database engine tuning advisor** it also count them as a single query instead of each one is independent queries

So I want to format them in a way that both SSMS should treat them as each one of them is a separate query

So even if one fails, SSMS should execute other working ones

What is the proper format for achieving this ?

Ty very much

what are these downvotes for ?

Comment: You should use `TRY` and `CATCH` for error handling. Others might suggest using `GO` between your statements.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu for example when i capture this query at profiler it is treated as a single batch query instead of each one is independent queries

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu go seems like working ty very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case an error can occur in any of your queries you should use [**TRY-CATCH**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) for this error handling.

Also, using [**GO**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) between your queries is an option.

Comment: ty for answer go seems like doing the trick. what is the logic behind this can you explain

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Just like you said in your question, if you review Profiler it looks as if it's one single batch of queries. By using `GO` you actually separate your queries in multiple batches. So, each query is ran by itself, independent of others. You can read the documentation for GO and TRY-CATCH on MSDN for even more details.